# How can I enable xterm 256 in ubuntu 8.04?

Tags: colors, xterm, ubuntu-8.04

How can xterm 256 be enabled in ubuntu 8.04? I was able to get that working in 9.10, but not 8.04.

Comment: michael, any update on your issue?  did the answer below help at all?  if it didn't can you edit the question and update with what you tried and what effect it had?

Answer (score 3):

I found that simply placing this in either your `.bash_profile` or `.profile` (if the former doesn't exist) works for me:

```
export TERM="xterm-256color"
```

Then either open a new terminal session or source the profile file `source ~/.bash_profile`. I'm assuming you use bash, but this will probably work for most shell type dot files.

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly in Ubuntu 11.10. edit: doh but it had side effects in Vim. Why on earth doesn't Ubuntu enable this by default so that we don't have to make these hacks?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Hardy (Ubuntu 8.04) doesn't provide the *terminfo* entry (*/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color*) in the default *ncurses* packages.  Karmic provides this entry in the *ncurses-base* package ([Karmic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/ncurses-base), [Hardy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/ncurses-base)), but Hardy provides it in the *ncurses-term* package ([Hardy](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/ncurses-term)).

I found this article on enabling [256-Color Xterms in Ubuntu](http://push.cx/2008/256-color-xterms-in-ubuntu).  To enable:

1. Install *ncurses-term*: `sudo aptitude install ncurses-term`
2. Customize the xterm entries; add this to *~/.Xdefaults*:

   ```
   *customization: -color
   XTerm*termName: xterm-256color
   ```
3. Add this to *~/.xsession* to apply to new terminals:

   ```
   if [ -f $HOME/.Xdefaults ]; then
      xrdb -merge $HOME/.Xdefaults
   fi
   ```
4. Log out and back in to pick up all changes, or just run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults`
5. Open a new xterm and test with `tput` and `echo $TERM`; you should see the following output:

   ```
   $ tput colors
   256
   $ echo $TERM
   xterm-256color
   ```

   If you do, you're good to go.

Additionally, some applications will need special configuration to take advantage of the new capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment on sa125's answer but I don't have enough rep.

Archlinux's wiki entry on xterm says the following about the TERM environmental variable:

> Allow xterm to report the TERM variable correctly. Do not set the TERM
> variable from your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile or similar file. The
> terminal itself should report the correct TERM to the system so that
> the proper terminfo file will be used. Two usable terminfo names are
> xterm and xterm-256color. To set the name, use the resource
>
> `XTerm.termName: xterm-256color`

So you probably want to set this variable from the `.Xresources` file instead of `.bashrc` or `.profile`